# webpack 4 react unexpected token ...(spread operator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

Recently i have implemented `Webpack 4` setup for my `react` app.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like this

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: './src/index.js',
  filename: './index.html',
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]',
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [htmlWebpackPlugin],
};
```

Here is my `package.json` scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Here the problem is when i use `...`(spread operator) it's throwing an `error` i believe this is something related to `babel` which is not properly transpiling. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

It throws an `error` something like the one below.

```
 ERROR in ./src/index.js
    Module build failed: SyntaxError: D:/cp/src/index.js: Unexpected token (31:6)

      29 |   return {
      30 |     headers: {
    > 31 |       ...headers,
         |       ^
      32 |       authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null,
      33 |     },
      34 |   };
```

Comment: `...` isn't (and can't be) an operator.

Comment: @kiarashws: The error is reported in a `.js` file, how will that help?

Comment: whats in your .babelrc?

Comment: @wgcrouch {
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just install `babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread` module.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread

Then add it to .babelrc:

```
"plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread",
  ],
```

Comment: if not using .babelrc then add the following to the webpack config under options for the module rule,      plugins:['transform-object-rest-spread']

Answer (score 3):

```
   "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread"
```

does not even have a github page. if you use this, you will see too much output on the console and there is no option to silent it or use "verbose". I suggest you to use
[@babel/plugin-transform-spread](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-transform-spread). then add this to the `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread"
  ]
}
```