# Why does using the spread operator in a reducer not give split values?

Tags: javascript, redux

```
import { createStore, bindActionCreators, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//Reducer's
//Reducers will hold the fields of a table
//Reducers is a function returning the next state using previous state
//Reducers accept a state and an action

const userStatus = (state = {name: 'Michael'}, action) => {

    //Checking the action type
    switch(action.type){

        case 'TOGGLE_STATUS':
            return {...state, action.value}

        default:
        return state

    }


} 
//Stores's

const store = createStore(combineReducers({ User: userStatus }))


//Action's

const myvalue = 'Testing'

const changeStatus = (coolvalue) => ({

    type: 'TOGGLE_STATUS',
    value: coolvalue

}
)

//Dispatch actions

store.dispatch(changeStatus(myvalue));
console.log(store.getState());
```

I am testing out redux, i am slightly confused about one thing. I am trying to return a new object with the state with some additional value passed in from the action. However, when i am using the spread operator on ...action.value, i get an object splitting up the string 'testing' like so:

User
:
0
:
"T"
1
:
"e"
2
:
"s"
3
:
"t"
4
:
"i"
5
:
"n"
6
:
"g"
name
:
"Michael"

I would like testing to be under the key of User like User: 'Testing'.
I have tried action.value which doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: It should be `action.value` not `...action.value`. You can do `...action` if you want.

Comment: Doesn't work, i get: Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected , (16:36)

Comment: Am i missing a plugin?

Comment: Yes, check this, probably it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327580/webpack-4-react-unexpected-token-spread-operator

Comment: Oh i figured it out! action.value would not give a key value pair to be stored in the new object! Thanks for your help! :)