# Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (three dots)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Having a small problem with the webpack. I have the following code which is not mine:

```
pointer.files = {
    ...pointer.files,
    [file]: 1
};
```

And I get the following error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (84:28)

  82 |                         pointer.files = pointer.files || {};
  83 |                         pointer.files = {
> 84 |                             ...pointer.files,
     |                             ^
  85 |                             [file]: 1
  86 |                         };
  87 |                     });
```

I usually don't use the `...` so I'm not sure what the problem. What would be the best way to replace the need of `...` with another syntax approach in order to make it work?

Comment: Another option would be to use `Object.assign({[file]: 1}, pointer.files)`

Comment: I think you are missing the property name to which assign `...pointer.files` value

Comment: what is `pointer.files` when not `{}`?

Comment: @DavideBulbarelli you can spread objects into other objects (as of ES9), so it doesn't need a property name

Comment: Sounds like babel is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I used `npm run watch` to build my javascript files and received the following error on the command line:

```
ERROR in ./react/src/common/components/RowPlaceholder.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (14:6)

  12 |       position: 'absolute',
  13 |       background: 'white',
> 14 |       ...style
     |       ^
  15 |     }}
  16 |   />
  17 | const buildStencil = stencil =>

 @ ./react/src/common/components/List.js 27:22-49
```

In the browser, the console showed the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./RowPlaceholder"
    webpackMissingModule List.js:5
    <anonymous> List.js:5
    Webpack 9
```

I could solve the problem by applying this solution based on [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50327987/15972591) on Stackoverflow:

1. `npm install babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread`
2. Create a .babelrc in the root directory of the project and add these lines

*(strange bug on Stackoverflow right now: when I leave this line of my answer empty the codeblock below is not rendered as code)*

```
{
   "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread",
  ],
}
```

The three dots are known as [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), by the way.

Comment: There are 2 extra commas in the .babelrc which will cause the build to error out.  Even with the commas removed, it unfortunately did not fix the error for me.